# Ошибки в разметке c charset. Как заменить старые теги c помощью css?

Tags: charset

Валидатор вывел следующие ошибки:
http://qps.ru/wMRX0

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

<title>home page</title>




<style>
    body {
        background: url(fons/Z3.jpg);
        /* Цвет фона и путь к файлу */
        
        color: #050505;
        /* Цвет текста */
        
        no-repeat;
        -moz-background-size: 100%;
        /* Firefox 3.6+ */
        
        -webkit-background-size: 100%;
        /* Safari 3.1+ и Chrome 4.0+ */
        
        -o-background-size: 100%;
        /* Opera 9.6+ */
        
        background-size: 100%;
    }
    /* Современные браузеры */
    
    a.button7 {
        font-weight: 700;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
        border-radius: 3px;
        background: rgb(64, 199, 129);
        box-shadow: 0 -3px rgb(53, 167, 110) inset;
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
    a.button7:hover {
        background: rgb(53, 167, 110);
    }
    a.button7:active {
        background: rgb(33, 147, 90);
        box-shadow: 0 3px rgb(33, 147, 90) inset;
    }
    a.button9 {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        color: #777674;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 1px 1px, rgba(100, 100, 100, .3) 3px 7px 3px;
        user-select: none;
        padding: 1em 2em;
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 3px / 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .0) 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .8), rgba(255, 255, 255, .0) 70%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(125, 125, 125, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(125, 125, 125, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(125, 125, 125, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(125, 125, 125, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(223, 190, 170, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(223, 190, 170, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(223, 190, 170, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(223, 190, 170, .5));
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 200% 100%, auto, 100% 2px, 100% 2px, 100% 1px, 100% 1px;
        background-position: 200% 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 4px, 0 calc(100% - 4px);
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 3px 10px 10px -10px;
    }
    a.button9:hover {
        transition: .5s linear;
        background-position: -200% 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 4px, 0 calc(100% - 4px);
    }
    a.button9:active {
        top: 1px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="1000" border="4" align="center" cellpadding="3">
    <div class="block-middle">
        <div class="img-block">
 

        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css">
            <div class="block-middle">
                <div class="img-block">
                    <img src="fons/z5.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="img-block">
                    <img src="fons/z5.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="img-block">
                    <img src="fons/z5.jpg">
                </div>


        </head>





        <table width="1000" border="4" align="center" cellpadding="3">


            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <p><font color="red" size="+3"><b>Astrovok<b></font>
                    </p>




                    <a href="index.html" class="button9">Главная страница </a>
                    <a href="calendar moon.html" class="button9"> Лунный календарь </a>
                    <a href="profailer.html" class="button9">Профессия по натальной карте </a>
                    <a href="kid.html" class="button9">Гороскоп ребёнка </a>
                    <a href="sinastriya.html" class="button9">Синастрия (совместимость) </a>
                    <a href="http://astrovok.iforum.name/pages/astrologiya_onlain" class="button9">Астрология онлайн </a>
                    <a href="http://astrovok.iforum.name" class="button9">Форум </a>
                    <a href="call.html" class="button9">Обратная связь </a>
                    <a href="http://astrovok.iforum.name/pages/programma_antaresweb" class="button9">Антарес </a>
                    <a href="http://astrovok.iforum.name/pages/konverter_vremeni" class="button9">Конвертр времени </a>
                    <a href="http://astrovok.iforum.name/pages/gadanie_po_knige_peremen" class="button9">Гадание по книге перемен </a>
                    <a href="http://astrovok.iforum.name/pages/tolkovanie_snovidenii" class="button9">Толкование сновидений онлайн </a>
                    <a href="karta.html" class="button9">Карта (пример) </a>
                    <a href="moon.html" class="button9">Все о Вашей луне (пример)</a>
                    <a href="karm.html" class="button9">Кармический гороскоп (пример) </a>
                    <a href="pow.html" class="button9">Сила планет</a>
                    <a href="fd.html" class="button9">Формула души</a>
                    <a href="cards.html" class="button9">Карты Любви Р.Кемпа</a>
                    <a href="/public_html/China/index.html" class="button9">Китайский гороскоп</a>

                    <a href="cards.html" class="button9">Карта сайта</a>
                    <hr>




                    <td style="width: 650px;" valign="top">
                        <!-- google_ad_section_start -->
                        <!--      <p align="center"><img src=".jpg"></p> -->
                        <h3 align="center" style="color:white">home page</h3>

                        <h3 align="center" style="color:white">text</h3>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 62px;" align="right" text="center" valign="top">

                                <script src="http://astro-app.net/apps-acl.js?RU132833ddffdd0033990022ee0014" id="acalendar"></script>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <!-- google_ad_section_end -->
                    </td>



                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://zornet.ru/ZORNET-RU/jquery.min_raketa.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://zornet.ru/ZORNET-RU/MrScrollUp_raketa.js"></script>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://zornet.ru/ZORNET-RU/MrScrollUp_raketa.css" />
                    <div id="MrScrollUp" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="MrScrollUp1"></div>
                        <div class="MrScrollUp2"></div>
                    </div>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 712px;" colspan="2" align="center">

                            <p><em><font color=white> При копировании материалов данного сайта, прямая ссылка на сайт обязательна</em>
                                <br /> © 2017</font>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
        </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">`? И ставить ВЫШЕ `<title>home page</title>`.

Comment: Исправлено. но сейчас выдаёт такие ошибки: [http://qps.ru/4EaI6] 1. Fatal Error: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.
From line 77, column 63; to line 78, column 26
dding="3">↩<div class="block-middle">↩                                               2. Malformed byte sequence  и 3 element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.  Как их поменять?

Comment: Если вы ставите кодировку страницы `utf-8`, то и информацию на страницу надо выводить в этой кодировке. Если информация выводится в другой кодировке, то указывайте верную кодировку в мета данных.

Comment: поменял кодировку на "windows-1251" теперь выдаёт такую ошибку( Warning: Legacy encoding windows-1251 used. Documents should use UTF-8.
http://astrovok.esy.es/